How to design a fence gate in a narrow area next to house?
I'm trying to figure out the best way to construct a new fence and gate in a narrow area next to my house. I am planning to have this fence be 6' tall and am considering using metal fence posts (Postmaster, Lifetime, etc.). The fence will be about 28" away from the house door. The side yard area is about 4.75' wide. This area includes a concrete sidewalk that is 1.5' away from the house foundation.
I would like the gate to swing toward the house and away from the side door to maximize the opening.
What is the best approach for a narrow area like this?

Gray is existing sidewalk.
Blue is property line.
White is side door entrance to the house.
Red is current fence location.
Purple is desired gate location and orientation.


Photo of the location in question:


There is no "best" way. There are a many tried and true ways of building a fence and gates. They all have varying levels of finish and aesthetics but it's up to your own personal preferences and budget so this is not something we can really answer for you.

Sure, but maybe I phrased it wrong. I'm just looking for a strong approach that will result in a long life and good functionality of the gate. So really hoping for answers that offer potential solutions because I can weigh on my own if they meet my budget/aesthetic requirements

put the gate hinge on the face of the fence post so that corner of the open gate does not protrude into the path.


Good thought. Although ideally I'd like the gate to be on the other post. I'm imaging it will be more out of the way of its against the house when open. And I'm mostly concerned structurally, I don't want sagging, bent post, etc.

yeah, sorrt I drew a mirror image. (or perhaps a worm's eye view).    structurally your existing gates look good,  and the hanging post seems connected to the house, so it should not sag.

Worm's eye view, I like that. I should say that the existing gate is going to be removed and will be replaced with a single door gate if possible. Also hoping to to attach to the house, the siding will get replaced soon and don't want that to be an issue.
